# Find and join 2 files from one day (16k files) in one command

Tags: unix

Someone gziped our aplication logs for one day before the day ends. And now we have gziped logs to 7 am. And new logs from 7am to 11:59 pm.
We woudle like to merge them into new archive that would include gzip and rest of the log.
We can't do it manualy because it's about 10k of pairs.
Logs are in many catalogs and we always used find plus exec gzip to gzip them.
They are named aplication_name_20180225.log and aplication_name_20180225.log.gzip and we woudl like to make a new gzip file from this two for example named aplication_name_20180225_all.log.gzip
We have unix in this machine.

Do you have any idea how to join them in one archive?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
gzip -c aplication_name_20180225.log >> aplication_name_20180225.log.gzip
mv aplication_name_20180225.log.gzip aplication_name_20180225_all.log.gzip
```

(It should be obvious how to automate this with `find` and `exec`.)